# Create a static array with pointers to a dynamic array c++

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to create a static array that has pointers to a dynamic array (that holds objects of a class I've created). I have a picture that better explains what I'm trying to do as well as the code I have. Also, it would be very helpful if someone was able to help give some guidance how to traverse this sort of data structure.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
    private:
    string name;
public:
     Person()
     {    
     }

     void getName()
     {
         cout << "just a test" << endl;    
     }
};

int main()
{

     Person bot();
     Person **bigArr;
     bigArr= new Person*[10]; // dynamic array (size 10) of pointers to int

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
         bigArr[i] = new Person[10];
         // each i-th pointer is now pointing to dynamic array (size 10) of actual int values

     }
     bigArr[0][0] = bot;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: `Person bot();` declares a function taking no arguments and returning `Person`. It doesn't declare a variable of type `Person`. Make it `Person bot;` Then add a missing `#include <string>`, and I'm pretty sure your program will compile.

Comment: since you are using C++, why not use a vector instead of a dynamic array?
would be much easier to have a static array point to that

Comment: It's true, they're much more bearable, but I'm currently restricted to this data structure

Comment: Also read up on the keyword `const`

Comment: @min state your restrictions in your question, we'd be guessing all day long otherwise

Comment: woops, sorry! The main restriction is having to use this exact data structure, i.e having a static array that points to dynamic arrays that can hold objects.

Comment: @igorTandetnik I just gave it a try, it is not compiling. I keep getting the error: no match for operator= in *(*bigArr)=bot

Comment: [Compiles for me](http://rextester.com/IESFA45143)

Comment: @igorTandetnik it worked! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Thanks so much everyone

Comment: Warning: You state you require a **static** array that points to **dynamic** arrays. `Person **bigArr;` is, as you state in a comment on the next line, going to be a dynamic, not a static, array. I think you want something more along the lines of `Person *bigArr[10];`

Comment: ^^^ be sure to read that comment. You don't have any static array in your code (yes yes, except the c string literals of course). Thus if your requirement is to have a static array, then you need to change this!

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a huge difference @user4581301